# Работа модели в MVC

Tags: model, mvc, view

Мне нужно выбрать конкретную статью по адресу `/blog/post/post_url`
Любая запись блога имеет комментарии. Статью одну я выбрал и вывел, но как быть с комментариями - их тоже надо как-то выводить. Метод модели (`get_blog_post($id)`) должен вернуть также и список комментариев? Или собирать массив комментариев из другого метода модели, например, `get_blog_post_comments($id)`, склеить с первым результатом и передать в представление? Или как еще?